# Children stored in an array in Parent's state don't receive new props

Tags: reactjs

I created a self contained little site to demonstrate this problem I'm having with React. Create an index.html file with the contained code and you will have a working demonstration of my problem.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/babel">

        class Child extends React.Component {
            render() {
                return(<p>Child {this.props.index} thinks toggle is {(this.props.toggleProp) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"}</p>);
            }
        }

        class Parent extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    toggle: false,
                    children: []
                }
            }

            buttonToggle() {
                let newChildren = this.state.children;
                newChildren.push(
                    <Child
                    key={this.state.children.length}
                    index={this.state.children.length}
                    toggleProp={this.state.toggle} />);

                this.setState({
                    toggle: !this.state.toggle,
                    children: newChildren
                });
            }

            render() {
                return <div>
                    <button onClick={() => this.buttonToggle()}>Click me</button>
                    <p>Parent thinks toggle is {(this.state.toggle) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"}</p>
                    <div>{this.state.children}</div>
                    </div>
                ;
            }
        }

        ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
        </script>    
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As I understand, the Child component will successfully receive a prop update when the Parent's state changes when you render the Child directly (such as putting `<Child ... />` directly in the Parent's render method), instead of providing a reference to the array of child components like this example shows. In this situation, every time you click the button, a new Child is created with a prop reflecting the current state of the Parent's boolean at the time of creation. However, as the boolean in the Parent's state changes, none of the created Child components receive a prop update. It is as if the value is **copied** instead of **referenced**.

Is this what is happening? In my actual application, I've got a list of dynamically created objects, so I am mutating an array that contains all the children and adding/removing items from this list per user action, and I have buttons in the Parent that affect all the children - information which I am passing in as a prop. Thus I have discovered this issue. I hope it isn't a bug. What can be done here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
import React from "react";

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <p>
        Child {this.props.index} thinks toggle is{" "}
        {this.props.toggleProp ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"}
      </p>
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      toggle: false,
      children: []
    };
  }

  buttonToggle() {
    const newChildren = [...this.state.children];

    newChildren.push({
      key: this.state.children.length - 1,
      index: this.state.children.length - 1
    });

    this.setState({
      toggle: !this.state.toggle,
      children: newChildren
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.buttonToggle()}>Click me</button>
        <p>Parent thinks toggle is {this.state.toggle ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"}</p>
        <div>
          {this.state.children.map(child => (
            <Child
              key={child.index}
              index={child.index}
              toggleProp={this.state.toggle}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Parent;
```

The problem in your code is with pushing the  item into your children's state array, it's saving the current state you've been giving to it. But you are not rerendering it with the new state. The above code will rerender the  components every time when the component updates. And will pass to its props the newly updated state.

If you can't use something like map, then you can stick with pushing but inside render method.

E.g

```
const childCount = this.state.childCount;
const childrenToRender = [];

for(let i = 0; i < childCount; i++){
  childrenToRender.push(<Child />);
}

return (
  <div>
    ...
    {childrenToRender}
  </div>
)
```

[image: Edit cranky-lovelace-f9fqz]

Answer (score 0):

First, the state is not "referenced", React synchronizes the value in state and the value displayed on UI by rerendering, not because they are sharing the same reference.

The child component is not updated with the latest value is because it's not rerendered. I guess the reason is **React only tries to rerender the child whose reference is updated**. (I cannot find any document about it but it matches the observation.) In your code since you are doing `newChildren.push(...)`, the old children's reference remain the same, so React didn't rerender them.

So if you follow Yusufbek's answer, either the "map" one or the "for loop" one,

```
{this.state.children.map(child => (
  <Child
    key={child.index}
    index={child.index}
    toggleProp={this.state.toggle}
  />
))}
```

it creates a new Child instance (even for the old Child!) every time the parent renders, so the child components will be rerendered as expected.